# Return record with max value using GROUP BY in SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, view, group-by

I have created this view in my sql server with this query :

```
SELECT        
    dbo.jointId.JointId, dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdetailId, 
    dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdate, dbo.fitupdetail.fitupnumber, 
    dbo.weldDetail.WeldDetailId, dbo.weldDetail.welddate, 
    dbo.weldDetail.weldnumber
FROM
    dbo.weldDetail 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.jointId ON dbo.weldDetail.jointid = dbo.jointId.JointId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.fitupdetail ON dbo.jointId.JointId = dbo.fitupdetail.jointid
```

The result of query is this :

[image]

But the result that i expected is selected in the picture ,i just need to record for each `jointID` that has a maximum value of `welddetailid` and `fitupdetailid`

Comment: Add `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JointID ORDER BY welddetailid)` in the end of statement. In the top `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`

Comment: @gofr1 could you please give me the whole query

Comment: You mean this query :SELECT   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES     dbo.jointId.JointId, dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdetailId, dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdate, dbo.fitupdetail.fitupnumber, dbo.weldDetail.WeldDetailId, dbo.weldDetail.welddate, 
                         dbo.weldDetail.weldnumber
FROM            dbo.weldDetail INNER JOIN
                         dbo.jointId ON dbo.weldDetail.jointid = dbo.jointId.JointId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.fitupdetail ON dbo.jointId.JointId = dbo.fitupdetail.jointid ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JointID ORDER BY welddetailid)

Comment: Yes, see my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  j.JointId, 
                        fd.fitupdetailId, 
                        fd.fitupdate, 
                        fd.fitupnumber, 
                        wD.WeldDetailId, 
                        wD.welddate, 
                        wD.weldnumber
FROM dbo.weldDetail wD
INNER JOIN dbo.jointId j
    ON wD.jointid = j.JointId 
INNER JOIN dbo.fitupdetail fd
    ON j.JointId = fd.jointid
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.JointID ORDER BY fd.fitupdetailId DESC, wD.welddetailid DESC)
```

Comment: I get this error :Error in ORDER BY clause.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: fixed query, add aliases.

Comment: Unable to parse query text.

Comment: SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: Just press OK :) Try this query without a view, just execute in another batch.

Comment: *SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.* is a common error, sometimes designer cannot represent query used for the view in a grid pane, f.e. when you use CTE inside the view

Comment: Thank you again dear friend it really solved my problems

Comment: Hi dear friend could you please take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243771/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-view